If an experiment is conducted on 1 class of 30 students, is that 1 data point or 30 data points?
Academic papers report language-learning experimental results using methods like those described here.  Often they take a class of students (say, 30) and randomly assign some task for one half, and the other half remains unchanged.
I worry such experiments give highly correlated experimental results:

the students are likely from the same language-learning class, and therefore are probably all learning the same language with the same teacher using the same methods (textbooks, study methods, etc.);
the students likely have comparable skill levels in their target language;
the students are likely from the same age bracket;
the students likely live in the same city, and have comparable backgrounds and native language(s);
the students likely have comparable language-learning goals (e.g., pass a specific upcoming test, or pass year-8 German); and
the students are usually tested on a single quantifiable outcome, such as number of words learned.

So it seems to me that an experiment for a class of 30 students should only be considered as 1 data point (or 1 data point repeated 30 times), equivalent as evidence to a (carefully verified) single anecdote ("it worked for my class").
However, this experimental design is common in research papers, so maybe there's a counterargument here.
Question: If an experiment is conducted on 1 class of 30 students, is that 1 data point or 30 data points?

Quantitative and qualitative
Quantitative research aims to capture variance, whereas qualitative aims to provide a rich description of what is happening. This does not capture the multitude of research methods, but is a good basic distinction to keep in mind. I understand that the question is about quantitative methods.
Practical issues
Most of psychological research has been done on university students with an emphasis on psychology students, because those populations are easily available to researchers, who often work at and maybe teach at a university.
For similar reason I would expect most of language learning research to be done on people who have enrolled to some kind of course or study program where they learn languages.
Research is hard and time-consuming. This, and the previous point together mean that we would usually expect research to take a minimum feasible group and easily accessible group and that is where things happen. This is often a single class or a couple of classes by the same teacher or at the same institute.
There are also practical issues, such as controlling the baseline skill level so that whatever the researchers do is even meaningful, which add a lot of complexity as the subject population turns more heterogeneous.
Generalizability
All this certainly leads to issues of generalizability. A single experiment done on a single class is suspect, but can still indicate what might be the case, and might be the best evidence we have, because research is hard. In any case, if the same method is tested in several different and independent experiments, and the results have a clear trend, that is nice.
Empirical science is often incremental in this sense, and depending on the field of research, people write meta-studies where they gather all sufficiently rigorous studies on a given theme and look for trends. This can be done statistically, if the articles themselves are quantitative, or in any case by simply seeing what has been done under what circumstances and summarizing.
Language learning is not my research field, so I do not know how quantitative it is in general, and whether there is a culture of meta-studies.
Some fields of medicine and physics aside, most of research does not aim for statistical certainty about a matter. In particular, in education, the effects are often fairly small and easily overwhelmed by everything else, such as the teacher, the classroom norms, the student or pupil population, what everyone is used to, constraints from the organizations involved, etc. Ultimately, in many situations, the fine differences between two methods in a speculative white room situation is simply not that interesting or crucial.
The actual answer
Whether a class is a single data point or thirty depends ultimately on the research question and the population one is looking at. Typically, the individual differences between the students or the pupils are large enough to use n = 30, if individual learning outcomes are what is being researched. Even then, a meta study can numerically combine these in different ways, and the distinction between a single data point and a bunch of them is something the statistician can take into account at that point.
So: It does not seem to be the right question to ask whether n = 30 or n = 1 in this case, without a specific context and use case in mind.

his is where survey statistics can help. Survey statistics are data points that summarize individual survey responses into actionable and meaningful results. For example, it can be the percentage of employees who love working at your company or the average amount of money potential customers would pay for your product. https://www.surveymonkey.com/curiosity/basic-statistics-we-do-math-for-you/
